# Help with the "Draw Inside" Feature

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was working on a logo when I ran across a problem that I've never experienced before. Here's pretty much how the logo breaks down.

There are two shield shapes. One is the outer shield (the brown shield), and on top of it is the inner shield (the blue shield with the white stroke). I needed to cover up everything underneath the bear, so I used "Draw Inside" with the inner shield selected, and drew a box to cover up what needed to be covered.

Does anyone know why there is a gap in between the box and the shield? I really have been scratching my head over this issue.

Image 1:

> [image]

Image 2:

> [image]

Comment: Do you mean the little white dashes you can see at the base of the blue shield? What does it look like when you go to View > Outlines? (CMD + Y or CTRL + Y) Are your white sun rays still intact underneath the cover up shape?

Answer (score 2):

you can use Object > clipping mask function to crop and fill the blue shield.

1) merge all white stroke with pathfinder tool
2) copy blue shield shape on the above merged white strokes.
3) go to object > clipping mask > make
4) you will see all cropped and filled area as your requirement

[image: sample iamge]